# Unity 3D Camera follow object keep the same axis X rotation

Tags: math, unity-game-engine

I currently have my camera following my "Player", but when I move forward with it the camera align the X rotation and Y. I want to follow my Player at a certain distance and to keep my X rotation, but I don't find how to do this.

Please can someone help me ? :)

Currently I'm doing this :

```
float distance = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, _playerPos.position);

cameraMove += Vector3.forward * (distance - DistanceFromPlayer);
transform.Translate(cameraMove);
```

But it makes the X rotation move, I want to keep the same angle with my "Player".

Comment: it'd be helpful if you posted the code you're using to move/rotate the camera

Answer (score 0):

Is the camera attached to the player? Or have you tried that? If you attach the camera to your player object, the camera will always keep the same distance and rotation away from your player.

Comment: No, I did not. I want my camera to auto rotate on the Y axe when my player is moving. But I'm gonna try your solution thanks :)

Comment: Hum, It is not possible, because I'm changing the player rotation when I'm pressing my right click and it makes me do loopings ;O

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead
`cameraMove += transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * (distance - DistanceFromPlayer);`
Not sure whether it will work, but worth a try. Let me know if it works.